# Installer created with Wix fails to be installed as system

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, silent-installer

I have a quite simple installer created with Wix Toolset. My users complaints that they can't deploy this installer as system user. They have to do it as user. However, I have learned that installers can be deployed as system user. Could anyone tell me what I need to do in my wxs file so that they can deploy it as system user?

Answer (score 3):

We typically deploy our MSIs using Microsoft SCCM as SYSTEM.  We use PSEXEC to invoke a CMD prompt as SYSTEM to do our dev testing before sending it to SCCM.  There are two reasons an installer would fail as SYSTEM:

1) User error:  I can't tell you how many times I've seen packages put into SCCM with invalid command line arguments.  One of my favorite is quotation marks get turned into Unicode quotation marks via email transmission.  Another is logging to a directory that doesn't exist.  Another is forgetting to tell the MSI to run silently.  It just sits there and hangs. Another awesome one is typing the MSI name wrong.   It's especially awesome because they almost give me an SCCM log when I ask for an MSI log.   No MSI log means it's not the MSI's fault.

2) Installer design error:   Have you tested your silent installs?  Do you have any custom actions that make assumptions about the user context / environment?  One of my old favorites (not)  was InstallShield InstallScript custom actions that would fail due to a poorly designed DCOM interface for talking to the MSI session handle.  It's been almost 10 years since that was fixed but I still come across installers now and then. Another example is assuming that the user will have rights to another machine or the internet (SYSTEM typically has neither in a corp environment.)

I'd start with testing as SYSTEM using PSEXEC. Log the install and see what the error is.  Otherwise you haven't really given us any details to give a specific answer for.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I will definitely try psexec. Thanks.

Comment: This is great information, @Dundar if this helped you, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should get them to do a verbose log of what happens when they do the install. There are issues sometimes related to user specific locations, for example a file going to the user's personal folder, what does that mean for the system account? Or the install or a custom action may assume that a drive letter mapped for a user is system wide (they're not - they are per user) and that can cause errors. That's what Chris is saying too - the context matters. The system account does not have access to the interactive user's desktop, the network, profile locations that make no sense for a non-interactive account and so on.

Comment: I will get the logs and let you know if I find something strange. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also am a SCCM user and regularly deploy apps through SCCM... This WIX installer also drived me crazy. But Christopher's reaction helped me...

1) If Wix installers get tested using PSexec, they probably work, SCCM, I don't know what it is, but installs keep failing without apparent reason. (but it fails installing as System is true)
Solution: incorporate psexec in your script in SCCM...
add your setup.exe & psexec.exe in your source folder. Use following syntax in your setup script:

- copy psexec.exe to your software source location.

  %~dp0PsExec.exe -accepteula \127.0.0.1 "%~dp0setup.exe" --quiet

2) @WIX dev team: also try to test with SCCM!

3) if above fails, you can also extend the suggestion with:

add following syntax in your setup script:

```
c:\windows\system32\net.exe user /add WixHelpInstaller PaSSW0rd
c:\windows\system32\net.exe localgroup administrators WixHelpInstaller /add
%~dp0PsExec.exe -accepteula  -u .\WixHelpInstaller -p PaSSW0rd \\127.0.0.1 "%~dp0setup.exe" --quiet
c:\windows\system32\net.exe user WixHelpInstaller /delete
```